# How to set Inspector in Numbers for macOS hidden by default?

Tags: macos, numbers

Whenever I open a spreadsheet in Numbers for macOS, the Inspector's Format tab opens up. I'd prefer to have it hidden by default.

Is there any way to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Numbers for macOS *remembers* the Inspector visibility setting for every spreadsheet when you close it. So, once you have hidden the Inspector for a spreadsheet and closed it, opening it subsequently will keep it hidden.

Comment: Right, but that doesn't change the default behaviour for new (ie previous unopened) spreadsheets, which is what bugs me about using Numbers. It costs 1 click **every** time I open a spreadsheet and want to maximize my screen real estate.

Comment: It bugged me that Apple has never attend this issue. I guess that nobody care about it, or Numbers is too low in use to spare some time trying to give a better user experience.